# IF(AND statement with multiple criterias

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to write a formula to include multiple criteria and can't seem to get it right.

The formula works as is however I need to include "SHOT10","SHOT20", "SH15" and "SH20"

```
=IF(AND(C5194="SHOT15",H5194="",I5194=""),E5194,"")
```

Can someone assist me with modifying the above formula?

Comment: It isn't clear what you're trying to achieve. Please show some example input, desired output, current output, and point out how the current output differs from the desired. [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) always helps.

Comment: Thanks for replying Jean-Francois.  Like I said above the formula works as is meaning if the condition if C5194 is shot15 and H5194 is blank and I5194 is also blank then it will return me the value of cell E5194 else it will return blank.  The issue now is that I now need to also consider SHOT10, SHOT20, SH15 and SH20 as well.  Meaning that if either SHOT15, SHOT10, SHOT20, SH15 or SH20 appears in C5194 and H5194 is blank and I5194 is also blank then return the value of E5194 else return blank.  The key is that all the conditions must be met for the value of E5194 be returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `AND(C5194="SHOT15",H5194="",I5194="")` is equivalent to saying:

```
C5194="SHOT15" And H5194="" And 15194=""
```

So what you have in VBA code is:

```
If C5194="SHOT15" And H5194="" And 15194="" Then
    ActiveCell = E5194
Else
    ActiveCell = ""
End
```

You can use AND( and OR( to specify different parameters.

For example, If I want to pickup 3 different values in 'A1', but make sure that 'B1' and 'C1' are blank, I can use:

```
=IF(AND(OR(A1="A",A1="B",A1="C"),B1="",C1=""),"True","False")
```

So in your case specifically:

> The issue now is that I now need to also consider SHOT10, SHOT20, SH15 and SH20 as well. Meaning that if either SHOT15, SHOT10, SHOT20, SH15 or SH20 appears in C5194 and H5194 is blank and I5194 is also blank then return the value of E5194 else return blank. The key is that all the conditions must be met for the value of E5194 be returned

Your formula becomes:

```
=IF(AND(OR(C5194="SHOT15",C5194="SHOT10",C5194="SHOT20",C5194="SH15",C5194="SH20"),H5194="",I5194=""),E5194,"")
```

**Edit:** Shorten Using an array constant per **barry houdini**:

```
=IF(AND(OR(C5194={"SHOT15","SHOT10","SHOT20","SH15","SH20"}),H5194="",I5194=""),E5194,"")
```

Comment: Excellent answer! Just an option to shorten the formula a little you can also use an "array constant" like this in the OR function: `=IF(AND(OR(C5194={"SHOT15","SHOT20","SH15","SH20"}),H5194="",I5194=""),E5194,"")`

Comment: Thanks for the assistance user1274820 and most of all the explanation.  I now see where I was going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(
    AND(
        OR( C5194="SHOT10", C5194="SHOT15", C5194="SHOT20", C5194="SH15", C5194="SH20" ),
        H5194="",
        I5194=""
       ),
    E5194,
    ""
   )
```

Comment: Consider adding an explanation as to how this helps the op. Also heed the comment of his as well since it appears to have an error.